# jQuery - left to right animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to do something similar this guy did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38981501/jquery-slider-on-click)

However, I want my animation to go from left to right as opposed to right to left.

Now since all divs are actually positioned `inline` i have tried to specify `direction: rtl` on the parent div, but it still does not work. (my view remains on the left side on the page, I would like to see the rightmost div first and then when I slide the left divs they move to the right).

Thank you.

L.E: Here is the solution for those interested http://jsfiddle.net/oq4p28wg/

Comment: I’m afraid `direction` property is useless in this case because it applies to text. What you probably need is to increase left margin iteratively instead of decreasing it as in the example you pointed at.

Comment: Please include all relevant code here in your question, not only in a link. If the link is to a Stack Overflow article, your can copy the relevant code here, provided you give [proper attribution](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).

Comment: I will keep that in mind, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From moving left to right in the example referenced they add `margin-left` to move between slides, until reaching a maximum number of slides. In your case to move in the opposite direction you will need to start with the maximum `margin-left` and substract margin to move from right to left in the slides until reaching the first slide and therefore `margin-left:0`.

Comment: Starting with a high value for margin-left (think 1920px * 4) wouldn't leave a lot of blank space in the left portion of the page? That's what I am getting now.

Comment: Actually, I've found the solution. You start with a negative left-margin, usually the sum of divs width, then you increment it. Thank you.